# How to regular monitoring the url in sketchup ruby plugin?

Tags: ruby, ping, sketchup

I try to regular monitoring the url in sketchup ruby plugin..

I search some code to do this function:

```
require 'ping' 
def every_n_seconds(n) 
    loop do 
        before= Time.now 
        yield 
        interval=n-(Time.now-before) 
        sleep(interval) if interval>0 
    end 
end 
every_n_seconds(50) do 
   pingresult=Ping.pingecho("www.google.com") 
   puts pingresult 
   if pingresult="true" 
        puts "t" 
    else 
        puts "f!" 
    end 
end
```

but in first line, I get the error:

> LoadError: C:/Program Files (x86)/SketchUp/SketchUp
>   2013/Plugins/xxx.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load --
>   ping

I want to find the `ping` class library  but I  find nothing..

so where I can find the ping class or

Has any other method to achieve that function?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just running **ping** yourself?

```
`ping -c 1 www.google.com`
if $?.exitstatus == 0
  puts "t"
else
  puts "f"
end
```

Or, even better:

```
def ping(url)
  `ping -c 4 #{url}`
  $?.exitstatus == 0
end

if ping("www.google.com")
  puts "t"
else
  puts "f"
end
```

Running on a separate thread:

```
def ping(url)
  `ping -c 4 #{url}`
  $?.exitstatus == 0
end

def every_n_seconds(n)
  loop do
    before= Time.now
    yield
    interval=n-(Time.now-before)
    sleep(interval) if interval>0
  end
end

ping_thread = Thread.new {
  every_n_seconds(50) do
    pingresult=ping("google.com")
    puts pingresult
    if pingresult
      puts "t"
    else
      puts "f!"
    end
  end
}

puts "Doing other things now..."

ping_thread.join()
```

Comment: thankx, it seems work now, but i found any other problem, i use the Thread.new to run the ping function , but the thread will stop when the script run to last..

Comment: Since I do not see the code you are actually running, and I do not completely understand why you are using multiple threads, I cannot give a truly accurate answer. For starters, are you using thread.join() at the end of your script, or are you just creating a new thread and running every_n_seconds() on it?

Comment: I updated the original post to include an example of running this on a separate thread...

Comment: thankx again! I run your code in the sketchup, I feel the thread is work, but the sketchup is no respond and need to force close.. do you know why?

Comment: I found the solution http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/ui#start_timer, thanks again

Comment: SketchUp 2013 and older uses Ruby 1.8 which has "green threads". MEaning they will still block SU. Also, the reason you could not require "ping" was because that is part of the Standard Library which SketchUp doesn't ship.